# Why can't I save styles (categorized, graduated) within a SpatiaLite layer in QGIS 2.16?

Tags: qgis, style, sqlite

I can't save graduated styles in a polygon sqlite layer in qgis 2.16.0 and 2.16.1. A friend of mine with 2.6.1 has the same problem.

when I change the styles to categorized or graduated and I want to save that style to my spatialite DB I get an error message: **"Error looking for style. The query was logged."** To prove the error: When I try to add the spatialite-layer to a new project, the graduated style is gone.

However, qgis can save simple styles in the sqlite, this works for me. But this is not what I want...

How can I fix it? I really liked the feature of saving layer styles easily into the sqlite database...

Comment: Can you be more precise about the "I can't save" part. What exactly is missing, where does it fail, is there an error message?

Comment: Matthias, I edited the question and posted the error message in bold.